# Multiple asp.net UI Projects in one solution to share master page

Tags: asp.net

I have searched under different keywords but am not sure if I have found one that is exactly what I'm looking for, even though I have to think it's been asked before. We have say 4 seperate asp.net projects today that we would like to combine into one master solution to share the same master page/ header control. We would have a tab control in the master page, each tab would point to a seperate project. We would need to pass information between projects. An example would be an account list selection from project 1 would need to be retained for project 2 when the user clicks on the project 2 tab. I have to think there is a way to implement this outside of something like iframes. Appreciate any thoughts/insight in advance.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good candidate for MVC (model-view-controller). Multiple projects can be loaded into one solution, and shared. If you want to eliminate duplicate views, you could use Razor to render partial or shared views, or a layout page. Ref http://www.asp.net/mvc for more info.

You mentioned iframes. If you're looking for a synchronized solution, you could try multiple views per controller. For an asynchronous solution, AJAX through jQuery etc could work (http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).